# update margin on resize

Tags: jquery, css, resize

I'm working on a simple slider and it's going well, (still learning jQuery). At the moment my slider calculates the window size and changes my (full screen) div width so the content stays in the screen. Obviously on a slider you want content to move, and here's the problem.

I use this to get my window width,

```
var lastWidth   = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width()!=lastWidth){
        //execute code.
        lastWidth = $(window).width();
    }
});
```

So the lastWidth variable stores the window's width. I use this variable like this

This gives and updates the width of all the divs inside my slidercontainer (#pageslider)

```
$("#pageslider div").css({"min-width": (lastWidth)});
```

This calculates how much the width of the #pageslider should be so that all the divs fit in there.

```
$("#pageslider").css({"min-width": (lastWidth * 4)});
```

And now we get to the problem. If a visitor clicks on the .portfolio class the #pageslider animates to the left because of the margin-left. The value that's given is the current width of the screen. This works fine.

But if the visitor changes the window width that value does not get updates because it's put in the CSS.

```
$('nav li a.portfolio').click(function(event){
    $('#pageslider').animate({
        "margin-left":-lastWidth},"slow");
});
```

So if the window width is 1920px and someone clicks on the .portfolio link the #pageslider will move 1920 to the left. But when the screen is resized it stays at 1920px to the left, allthough it should change to the current screen size.

Here is a small jsfiddle with the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/L29pq/

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to keep margin-left as a percentage?

Comment: It might be, I'll try it out. I fixed the problem, for some reason I forgot about my resize bit... I just put my code inside the resize bit and now the margin gets updated :).

Comment: I was about to say that. Also, If all the frames (portfolio etc) are of same size, you can get the resize part out of jQuery and let CSS handle it maybe. Just a thought but I think its possible.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma: it would show the animation once again rite?

Comment: I did, but obviously I eddited the animation part out ;).

Answer (score 0):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/L29pq/6/)

What I did was add a variable `active` which keeps a record of how much to the left you have to shift, in terms of multiplier of `lastWidth`. On click on `home` its `0`. On click on `portfolio` its `1`, and so on.

**jQuery**

```
var lastWidth = $(window).width();
var active = 0;

$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() != lastWidth) {
        lastWidth = $(window).width();
        $("#pageslider div").css({
            "min-width": (lastWidth)
        });
        $("#pageslider").css({
            "min-width": (lastWidth * 4)
        });

        $('#pageslider').css({
            "margin-left": -lastWidth * active
        });
    }
});

$("#pageslider div").css({
    "min-width": (lastWidth)
});
$("#pageslider").css({
    "min-width": (lastWidth * 4)
});

$('nav li a.portfolio , h1 a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = this.href;
});

$('nav li a.portfolio').click(function (event) {
    $('#pageslider').animate({
        "margin-left": -lastWidth
    }, "slow");
    active = 1;
});

$('h1 a').click(function (event) {
    $('#pageslider').animate({
        "margin-left": '0px'
    }, "slow");
    active = 0;
});
```